# AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, telebot

Всем привет,пишу бота на питоне.Подключил бибилиотек telegram.ext ,но почему то функции не видят аргумента bot, но при этом update видит,если передавать context вместо bot передает контекст.Из-за этого не могу получить данные на бэке,должен выдавать словарь,но по сути выдавать нечего,кроме[image: введите сюда описание изображения] переданного контекста.

Лог ошибки
in line 20, in talk_to_me
user_text="Ïðèâåò {}! Òû íàïèñàë {}".format(update.message.chat.first_name, update.message.text)
AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: не вижу исспользования переменной bot

Comment: ее не использую пока что,но и update как будто не работает,или работает не так

Comment: ты в курсе что update должен быть вызываем трижды то есть функции message и chat должны возвращать вызываемые объекты... ну и тут ты перемудрил... простое лучше чем сложное

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: уверен, что всё понятно?

Comment: пока что не понял,в каком смысле update должен быть вызываем трижды?если можно пример

Answer (score 0):

либо не вызываем, но иметь вложеность словаря три причём переменные message chat должны быть объявлены то есть

```
#функция вернёт пустой список с которым можно делать что хочешь
         return []
a().append(1)
print(a()) #выведет пустой список так как функция вызвана НОВЫЙ раз
ты же пытаешься сделать что-то вида
def b():
     return [[],['x']]
b()[1][0]
```

то есть получить доступ к объекту, который должен вернуть другой объект (именно вернуть а не иметь способ вызова)
то же действительно и для классов. Как я ранее говорил, тройной доступ ужасен,- он трудно понимаем. лучше исспользовать переменные, пусть и лишние
то есть как то так:

```
c=b()
#[[],['x']]
cc=c[1]
ccc=cc[0]
```

по крайней мере во время разработки
[добавлено]
ответил тут ибо в комментах не удобно

Comment: Примерно понял,спасибо,попробую